# Inline editing in reports - page layout for this record doesn't allow edits

Tags: reporting, inline-editing

I am new to Salesforce and VF.

I created a bunch of custom fields and put them into a VF page. The page works fine, I can edit the fields and save them.

The problem is the following: I wanted to create a report with these fields, but in the report it does not allow me to edit the fields. There is the lock symbol and when I hover over it, it says "The page layout for this record doesn't allow edits."
Is there a way to enable inline editing for these fields in a custom report?

I have already enabled the general Inline Editing in Reports:

[image: The general inline editing is enabled]

API version: 55.0

My code:

```
<apex:page standardController="Onboarding__c">
    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageBlock title="Onboarding Tasks" mode="edit">
            <apex:pageBlockButtons >
                <apex:commandButton action="{!save}" value="Save"/>
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>
            <apex:pageBlockSection title="Before Kickoff Call" columns="3">
                <apex:inputField value="{!Onboarding__c.A_ZD_ticket_for_hosting_escalation_Opt__c}"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!Onboarding__c.A_Date_Completed__c}"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!Onboarding__c.A_Hours_Effort__c}"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!Onboarding__c.B_ReviewAndupdate_SF_Clinic_and_Opp_Info__c}"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!Onboarding__c.B_Date_Completed__c}"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!Onboarding__c.B_Hours_Effort__c}"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!Onboarding__c.C_Prep_Kickoff_Deck__c}"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!Onboarding__c.C_Date_Completed__c}"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!Onboarding__c.C_Hours_Effort__c}"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!Onboarding__c.D_Prep_convo_based_Twilio_ticket_outcom__c}"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!Onboarding__c.D_Date_Completed__c}"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!Onboarding__c.D_Hours_Effort__c}"/>
             </apex:pageBlockSection>
                
             <apex:pageBlockSection title="Kickoff Call" columns="3">
                <apex:inputField value="{!Onboarding__c.E_Host_Kickoff_Call__c}"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!Onboarding__c.E_Date_Completed__c}"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!Onboarding__c.E_Hours_Effort__c}"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!Onboarding__c.F_Kickoff_Call_Follow_up__c}"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!Onboarding__c.F_Date_Completed__c}"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!Onboarding__c.F_Hours_Effort__c}"/>
             </apex:pageBlockSection>
                
             <apex:pageBlockSection title="Before Admin Call" columns="3">
                <apex:inputField value="{!Onboarding__c.G_If_Terminals_purchased_Create_ZD_tick__c}"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!Onboarding__c.G_Date_Completed__c}"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!Onboarding__c.G_Hours_Effort__c}"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!Onboarding__c.H_Add_users_to_TeleVet_Academy__c}"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!Onboarding__c.H_Date_Completed__c}"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!Onboarding__c.H_Hours_Effort__c}"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!Onboarding__c.I_Setup_Texting_Video_and_Phone_Calls__c}"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!Onboarding__c.I_Date_Completed__c}"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!Onboarding__c.I_Hours_Effort__c}"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!Onboarding__c.J_Setup_Digital_Forms__c}"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!Onboarding__c.J_Date_Completed__c}"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!Onboarding__c.J_Hours_Effort__c}"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!Onboarding__c.K_Website_Widget_Pet_Portal__c}"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!Onboarding__c.K_Date_Completed__c}"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!Onboarding__c.K_Hours_Effort__c}"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!Onboarding__c.L_Send_Stripe_instructions__c}"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!Onboarding__c.L_Date_Completed__c}"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!Onboarding__c.L_Hours_Effort__c}"/>
             </apex:pageBlockSection>   
                
             <apex:pageBlockSection title="Admin Call" columns="3">
                <apex:inputField value="{!Onboarding__c.M_Host_Admin_Call__c}"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!Onboarding__c.M_Date_Completed__c}"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!Onboarding__c.M_Hours_Effort__c}"/>
             </apex:pageBlockSection>   
                
             <apex:pageBlockSection title="Post Admin Call" columns="3"> 
                <apex:inputField value="{!Onboarding__c.N_Texting_Send_letter_of_Authorization__c}"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!Onboarding__c.N_Date_Completed__c}"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!Onboarding__c.N_Hours_Effort__c}"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!Onboarding__c.O_Automations_Before_During_After_Vis__c}"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!Onboarding__c.O_Date_Completed__c}"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!Onboarding__c.O_Hours_Effort__c}"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!Onboarding__c.P_User_Training_Prep_script_agenda__c}"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!Onboarding__c.P_Date_Completed__c}"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!Onboarding__c.P_Hours_Effort__c}"/>
              </apex:pageBlockSection>   
                
             <apex:pageBlockSection title="User Training" columns="3">                
                <apex:inputField value="{!Onboarding__c.Q_Host_User_training__c}"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!Onboarding__c.Q_Date_Completed__c}"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!Onboarding__c.Q_Hours_Effort__c}"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!Onboarding__c.R_Follow_up_email_to_User_Training__c}"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!Onboarding__c.R_Date_Completed__c}"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!Onboarding__c.R_Hours_Effort__c}"/>
             </apex:pageBlockSection>   
                
             <apex:pageBlockSection title="Go Live Validation Meeting" columns="3">                 
                <apex:inputField value="{!Onboarding__c.S_Go_Live_Validation_Meeting__c}"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!Onboarding__c.S_Date_Completed__c}"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!Onboarding__c.S_Hours_Effort__c}"/>
             </apex:pageBlockSection>   
                
             <apex:pageBlockSection title="Internal Handoff to CSM Meeting" columns="3">                 
                <apex:inputField value="{!Onboarding__c.T_Prep_for_Internal_Handoff_to_CSM__c}"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!Onboarding__c.T_Date_Completed__c}"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!Onboarding__c.T_Hours_Effort__c}"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!Onboarding__c.U_Internal_Handoff_to_CSM_Meeting__c}"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!Onboarding__c.U_Date_Completed__c}"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!Onboarding__c.U_Hours_Effort__c}"/>
             </apex:pageBlockSection>   
                
             <apex:pageBlockSection title="Go Live" columns="3">                 
                <apex:inputField value="{!Onboarding__c.V_Go_Live__c}"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!Onboarding__c.V_Date_Completed__c}"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!Onboarding__c.V_Hours_Effort__c}"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!Onboarding__c.W_Handoff_email_to_CSM_and_Support__c}"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!Onboarding__c.W_Date_Completed__c}"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!Onboarding__c.W_Hours_Effort__c}"/>              
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with your VF page. It's likely a permission issue ([FLS](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=admin_fls.htm&type=5&language=en_US), [sharing](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=security_about_sharing_rules.htm&type=5&language=en_US)) or the field type isn't one that [inline edit can work with](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_rd_reports_inline_editing.htm&type=5&release=232).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure at least one of your fields on the report is a summary field.  If not, it locks all of them.  This took me several hours to figure out.